# JxtaSocketAddress.getPeerID() returns null on JXME

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

I'm running an JxtaServerSocket on JXME. Unfortunately, I am not able to get the remote peer id of the connected Socket:

```
JxtaSocket jsocket = (JxtaSocket) socket;
JxtaSocketAddress addr = ((JxtaSocketAddress) jsocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
```

addr.getPeerID() is null.
It works on JXSE, but I am lost on JXME. Has someone an idea?

Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JXME has not been maintained at least since JXTA release 2.5 (no one in the community was taking on that duty). We found several bugs in JXTA 2.5 and corrected them in 2.6 and 2.7. We implemented JUnit tests for regressions etc... That has never been made in JXME.

There are most probably several bugs left in JXME, which would explain your issue.